# Pillow AttributeError: 'PhotoImage' object has no attribute '_PhotoImage__photo'

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-imaging-library

I know that this has been answered already, but my situation is *slightly* different, and in that question, I found no answers.

**Original Code:**

```
import Tkinter as tk
from PIL import Image, ImageTk
import pathlib

win = tk.Tk()
win.title('Chess')
img = ImageTk.PhotoImage(file='Blackvariant-Button-Ui-System-Apps-Chess.png')
win.iconphoto(True, img)

#this class controls the viewing of the game and calculating the legal moves. eg if a pawn on e2 can move to e5 and drawing the board
class Game:
    #start of the Game class

    #init
    def __init__(self,root):

        print('The class has been declared')

        #creates the canvas
        self.base = tk.Canvas(win,bg='#f0d9b5',width='400',height='400')

    #function to draw the base chess board(the squares)
    def drawBoard(self):

        #variable declarations

        i = 1
        x = 0
        y = 0

        #test
        self.base.create_rectangle(0,0,100,100,fill='#b58862',)

        #create crucial isWhite variable
        isWhite = True

        #board drawing  loop
        while i < 65:

            i += 1

            #if statement draws all the brown squares on the board
            if isWhite == False:

                self.base.create_rectangle(x,y,x+100,y+100,fill='#b58862',outline = '#b58862')
                #debug
                print('drew a brown square at coordinates x =', x ,'y =', y)

                #some logic to know how and where to draw the next square
                if x == 350:
                    y += 50
                    x = 0
                    continue

                else:
                    x += 50
                    isWhite = True
                    continue

            #if statement draws all the white squares on the board
            if isWhite:
                self.base.create_rectangle(x,y,x+100,y+100,fill='#f0d9b5', outline='#f0d9b5')
                #debug
                print('drew a white square at coordinates x =', x ,'y =', y)

                #some logic to know how and where to draw the next square
                if x == 350:
                    y += 50
                    x = 0
                    continue

                else:
                    x += 50
                    isWhite = False
                    continue
        #packs canvas
        self.base.pack()

    #end of drawBoard()

    #this class draws the pieces from an array of the pieces' locations
    def drawPieces(self):

    

path = str(pathlib.Path(__file__).parent.absolute()) + '/Chess/Sprites/W_K.png'
        norm_img = Image.open(path)
        img = norm_img.resize((50,50))
        photo = ImageTk.PhotoImage(image=img)
        king = self.base.create_image((100,100),image=photo)

#end of the Game class


#creates new instance of the Game class
game = Game(win)
#runs the drawBoard function
game.drawBoard()
#runs the drawPieces function
game.drawPieces()
#main loop
win.mainloop()
```

**My Original Console:**

```
munmun@Munmuns-Air Coding % /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/bin/python3 "/Users/munmun/Desktop/Babai's Folder/Coding/Python/Projects/Chess/Chess AI.py"
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/munmun/Desktop/Babai's Folder/Coding/Python/Projects/Chess/Chess AI.py", line 7, in <module>
    img = ImageTk.PhotoImage(file='Blackvariant-Button-Ui-System-Apps-Chess.png')
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/PIL/ImageTk.py", line 89, in __init__
    image = _get_image_from_kw(kw)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/PIL/ImageTk.py", line 58, in _get_image_from_kw
    return Image.open(source)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/PIL/Image.py", line 2904, in open
    fp = builtins.open(filename, "rb")
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'Blackvariant-Button-Ui-System-Apps-Chess.png'
Exception ignored in: <function PhotoImage.__del__ at 0x7fee180a8040>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/PIL/ImageTk.py", line 118, in __del__
    name = self.__photo.name
AttributeError: 'PhotoImage' object has no attribute '_PhotoImage__photo'
munmun@Munmuns-Air Coding %
```

**Code that causes the problem:**

```
path = str(pathlib.Path(__file__).parent.absolute()) + '/Chess/Sprites/W_K.png'
norm_img = Image.open(path)
img = norm_img.resize((50,50))
photo = ImageTk.PhotoImage(image=img)
king = self.base.create_image((100,100),image=photo)
```

If I make a new file and import the correct libraries and canvas and such, then it works just *fine*!

Some People are saying that these lines of code are causing the problem:

```
img = ImageTk.PhotoImage(file='Blackvariant-Button-Ui-System-Apps-Chess.png')
win.iconphoto(True, img)
```

But they're not. If I remove these lines of code:

```
path = str(pathlib.Path(__file__).parent.absolute()) + '/Chess/Sprites/W_K.png'
    norm_img = Image.open(path)
    img = norm_img.resize((50,50))
    photo = ImageTk.PhotoImage(image=img)
    king = self.base.create_image((100,100),image=photo)
```

**That image loads and imports perfectly!**

Ok, if I *do* remove those lines of code, I get a FileNotFound error, which is fine and I fix it. It now runs... but the Image doesn't load!!!!!

If I make a new file and import the correct libraries and canvas and such, then it works just *fine*!

**Current Code:**

```
import tkinter as tk
from PIL import Image, ImageTk 
import pathlib

win = tk.Tk()
win.title('Chess')








#this class controls the viewing of the game and calculating the legal moves. eg if a pawn on e2 can move to e5 and drawing the board
class Game:

    #start of the Game class
    #start of the Game class
    #start of the Game class
    #start of the Game class
    #start of the Game class

    #init
    def __init__(self,root):

        print('The class has been declared')

        #creates the canvas
        self.base = tk.Canvas(win,bg='#f0d9b5',width='400',height='400')



    #function to draw the base chess board(the squares)
    def drawBoard(self):       

        #variable declarations

        i = 1
        x = 0
        y = 0

        #test
        self.base.create_rectangle(0,0,100,100,fill='#b58862',)

        #create crucial isWhite variable
        isWhite = True

        #board drawing  loop
        while i < 65:

            
            i += 1

            #if statement draws all the brown squares on the board
            if isWhite == False:

                self.base.create_rectangle(x,y,x+100,y+100,fill='#b58862',outline = '#b58862')
                #debug
                print('drew a brown square at coordinates x =', x ,'y =', y)
                
                #some logic to know how and where to draw the next square
                if x == 350:
                    y += 50
                    x = 0
                    continue
                
                else:
                    x += 50
                    isWhite = True
                    continue
                
                
            #if statement draws all the white squares on the board
            if isWhite:
                self.base.create_rectangle(x,y,x+100,y+100,fill='#f0d9b5', outline='#f0d9b5')
                #debug
                print('drew a white square at coordinates x =', x ,'y =', y)
                
                #some logic to know how and where to draw the next square
                if x == 350:
                    y += 50
                    x = 0
                    continue
                
                else:
                    x += 50
                    isWhite = False
                    continue
        #packs canvas                      
        self.base.pack()

    #end of drawBoard()

    #this class draws the pieces from an array of the pieces' locations
    def drawPieces(self):
        
        path = str(pathlib.Path(__file__).parent.absolute()) + '/Sprites/W_K.png'
        print('Path:' , path)
        norm_img = Image.open(path)
        img = norm_img.resize((50,50))
        photo = ImageTk.PhotoImage(image=img)
        king = self.base.create_image((100,100),image=photo)

#end of the Game class
#end of the Game class
#end of the Game class
#end of the Game class
#end of the Game class
#end of the Game class





#creates new instance of the Game class
game = Game(win)

#runs the drawBoard function
game.drawBoard()

#runs the drawPieces function
game.drawPieces()

#main loop
win.mainloop()
```

**Current Console:**

```
munmun@Munmuns-Air Chess % /usr/local/bin/python3 "/Users/munmun/Desktop/Babai's Folder/Coding/Python/Projects/Chess/Chess AI.py"
The class has been declared
drew a white square at coordinates x = 0 y = 0
drew a brown square at coordinates x = 50 y = 0
drew a white square at coordinates x = 100 y = 0
drew a brown square at coordinates x = 150 y = 0
drew a white square at coordinates x = 200 y = 0
drew a brown square at coordinates x = 250 y = 0
drew a white square at coordinates x = 300 y = 0
drew a brown square at coordinates x = 350 y = 0
drew a brown square at coordinates x = 0 y = 50
drew a white square at coordinates x = 50 y = 50
drew a brown square at coordinates x = 100 y = 50
drew a white square at coordinates x = 150 y = 50
drew a brown square at coordinates x = 200 y = 50
drew a white square at coordinates x = 250 y = 50
drew a brown square at coordinates x = 300 y = 50
drew a white square at coordinates x = 350 y = 50
drew a white square at coordinates x = 0 y = 100
drew a brown square at coordinates x = 50 y = 100
drew a white square at coordinates x = 100 y = 100
drew a brown square at coordinates x = 150 y = 100
drew a white square at coordinates x = 200 y = 100
drew a brown square at coordinates x = 250 y = 100
drew a white square at coordinates x = 300 y = 100
drew a brown square at coordinates x = 350 y = 100
drew a brown square at coordinates x = 0 y = 150
drew a white square at coordinates x = 50 y = 150
drew a brown square at coordinates x = 100 y = 150
drew a white square at coordinates x = 150 y = 150
drew a brown square at coordinates x = 200 y = 150
drew a white square at coordinates x = 250 y = 150
drew a brown square at coordinates x = 300 y = 150
drew a white square at coordinates x = 350 y = 150
drew a white square at coordinates x = 0 y = 200
drew a brown square at coordinates x = 50 y = 200
drew a white square at coordinates x = 100 y = 200
drew a brown square at coordinates x = 150 y = 200
drew a white square at coordinates x = 200 y = 200
drew a brown square at coordinates x = 250 y = 200
drew a white square at coordinates x = 300 y = 200
drew a brown square at coordinates x = 350 y = 200
drew a brown square at coordinates x = 0 y = 250
drew a white square at coordinates x = 50 y = 250
drew a brown square at coordinates x = 100 y = 250
drew a white square at coordinates x = 150 y = 250
drew a brown square at coordinates x = 200 y = 250
drew a white square at coordinates x = 250 y = 250
drew a brown square at coordinates x = 300 y = 250
drew a white square at coordinates x = 350 y = 250
drew a white square at coordinates x = 0 y = 300
drew a brown square at coordinates x = 50 y = 300
drew a white square at coordinates x = 100 y = 300
drew a brown square at coordinates x = 150 y = 300
drew a white square at coordinates x = 200 y = 300
drew a brown square at coordinates x = 250 y = 300
drew a white square at coordinates x = 300 y = 300
drew a brown square at coordinates x = 350 y = 300
drew a brown square at coordinates x = 0 y = 350
drew a white square at coordinates x = 50 y = 350
drew a brown square at coordinates x = 100 y = 350
drew a white square at coordinates x = 150 y = 350
drew a brown square at coordinates x = 200 y = 350
drew a white square at coordinates x = 250 y = 350
drew a brown square at coordinates x = 300 y = 350
drew a white square at coordinates x = 350 y = 350
Path: /Users/munmun/Desktop/Babai's Folder/Coding/Python/Projects/Chess/Sprites/W_K.png
```

Comment: I don't think it's the cause of you current problem, but I noticed another reading your code — see [Why does Tkinter image not show up if created in a function?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16424091/why-does-tkinter-image-not-show-up-if-created-in-a-function)

Comment: Adding self. in front of my PhotoImage and every other variable in the code (as the thread that you have posted suggests) doesn't do a thing. It's still there!